# Which is a best Tag Cloud plugin to work with jquery?

Tags: jquery

**Which is the best tag cloud plugin to work with jquery?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-sphere3d/examples/tag-cloud/

Comment: How to use this plugin(Installation features)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple center weighted one the other day.
http://blog.onnerby.se/p/jdoecloud.html